MPI_Op_create and MPI_Reduce in Fortran 2008
I have been trying (with not much success) to do MPI reduction using a custom operation in Fortran 2008. I managed to do this in C, but information is a bit more scarce on Fortran 2008.
This code works with the included MPI_SUM reduction function. It simply sums each existing rank value into a global sum. My immediate goal would be to define a user function, to do basically the same. Any help?
program main

    use mpi_f08
    implicit none

    integer :: ierror, isize, irank
    integer :: local_value, global_value

    call MPI_INIT(ierror)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, isize)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, irank)

    if (irank == 0) then

        local_value = irank
        global_value = 0
        call MPI_Reduce(local_value, global_value, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)

        print *, "global_value", global_value

    else ! MPI if rank > 0

        local_value = irank
        call MPI_Reduce(local_value, global_value, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)

    end if ! MPI if rank

    call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)

end program main

I managed to write a functional implementation in Fortran, but for some reason the output using 4 MPI processes was 3 instead of 6. No clue why. Still, I need a (correctly) working Fortran 2008 implementation to move forward.
EDIT - here is the fortran code that compiles, but does not run properly
    program main

    use mpi
    implicit none

    integer :: local_value, global_sum
    integer :: ierr, rank, size
    integer :: my_op

    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)

    call MPI_Op_create(custom_sum_op, .true., my_op, ierr)

    if (rank == 0) then

        local_value = rank
        global_sum = 0
        call MPI_Reduce(local_value, global_sum, 1, MPI_INT, my_op, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        print *, "Global sum: ", global_sum

    else ! irank > 0

        local_value = rank
        call MPI_Reduce(local_value, global_sum, 1, MPI_INT, my_op, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

    endif ! MPI if rank 0

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

contains

subroutine custom_sum_op(res, a)
    integer, intent(inout) :: res
    integer, intent(in) :: a
    res = a + res
end subroutine custom_sum_op

end program main


Welcome. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You can add a version tag for version-specific questions bit this is not one of them. The modern MPI API is also used in later Fortran standard versions.

Do not use MPI_INT for Fortran, it is a C datatype. Also, the ierror arguments are optional, you can avoid them, if you do not check them anyway.

It could well help if you edit the question to show your buggy Fortran implementation. The problem might not be where you think.

https://github.com/VictorEijkhout/TheArtOfHPC_vol2_parallelprogramming/blob/main/examples/mpi/f08/reductpositive.F90

The subroutine is an internal one. The pointer to it will only be valid when the containing code is still running. For the main program, that should be OK, but with MPI, stacks sometimes do strange things. It does not cause the issue here, but could cause issues in the future.

Thank you all, I've updated the question with the (non-functioning) fortran version.

Here's an example that works, with the interface for the user defined function taken from the MPI standard. What you have certainly doesn't match what the standard says; you only have 2 arguments instead of 4, they are of the wrong type for the mpi_f08 interface, and you are returning the result in the first argument, not the second.
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat op_create.f90
Module my_sum_module

  Implicit None

  Public :: my_sum
  
  Private
  
Contains

  Subroutine my_sum( invec, inoutvec, len, datatype )

    Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : stdout => output_unit
    Use, Intrinsic :: iso_C_binding  , Only : c_ptr

    Use mpi_f08
    
    Implicit None

    Type( c_ptr )       , Value :: invec
    Type( c_ptr )       , Value :: inoutvec
    Integer                     :: len
    Type( mpi_datatype )        :: datatype

    Integer, Dimension( : ), Pointer :: in_fptr
    Integer, Dimension( : ), Pointer :: inout_fptr

    If( datatype == mpi_integer ) Then
       Call c_f_pointer( invec   , in_fptr   , [ len ] )
       Call c_f_pointer( inoutvec, inout_fptr, [ len ] )
       inout_fptr = inout_fptr + in_fptr
    Else
       Write( stdout, * ) 'Unkown data type in my_sum'
       Call mpi_abort( mpi_comm_world, 5 )
    End If
    
  End Subroutine my_sum

End Module my_sum_module

Program test

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : stdout => output_unit

  Use mpi_f08, Only : mpi_comm_world
  Use mpi_f08, Only : mpi_integer
  Use mpi_f08, Only : mpi_sum
  Use mpi_f08, Only : mpi_op
  Use mpi_f08, Only : mpi_init, mpi_finalize
  Use mpi_f08, Only : mpi_comm_rank, mpi_comm_size
  Use mpi_f08, Only : mpi_reduce
  Use mpi_f08, Only : mpi_op_create
  
  Use my_sum_module, Only : my_sum

  Implicit None

  Type( mpi_op ) :: op

  Integer :: root
  Integer :: answer
  
  Integer :: me, nproc

  Call mpi_init()
  Call mpi_comm_rank( mpi_comm_world, me    )
  Call mpi_comm_size( mpi_comm_world, nproc )

  If( me == 0 ) Then
     Write( stdout, * ) 'Running on', nproc, ' processes'
  End If

  root = 0

  Call mpi_reduce( me, answer, 1, mpi_integer, mpi_sum, root, mpi_comm_world ) 
  If( me == root ) Then
     Write( stdout, * ) 'Answer to sum = ', answer
  End If

  Call mpi_op_create( my_sum, .True., op )
  Call mpi_reduce( me, answer, 1, mpi_integer, op, root, mpi_comm_world ) 
  If( me == root ) Then
     Write( stdout, * ) 'Answer to my_sum = ', answer
  End If

  Call mpi_finalize()
  
End Program test
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpif90 --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpif90 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -O -g -std=f2018 op_create.f90 
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 1 ./a.out
 Running on           1  processes
 Answer to sum =            0
 Answer to my_sum =            0
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 2 ./a.out
 Running on           2  processes
 Answer to sum =            1
 Answer to my_sum =            1
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 3 ./a.out
 Running on           3  processes
 Answer to sum =            3
 Answer to my_sum =            3
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
 Running on           4  processes
 Answer to sum =            6
 Answer to my_sum =            6
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 5 --oversubscribe ./a.out
 Running on           5  processes
 Answer to sum =           10
 Answer to my_sum =           10
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ 


Thank you! I see the code structure of declaring the custom function, together with the use of pointers make this seemingly simple task a bit more complex than I initially expected. Cheers :)
